# How To Properly use QuantLib to Replicate Excel's MDURATION Function

Tags: fixed-income, quantlib

just wanted to ask how to use Quantlib on replicating Excel's MDURATION.

Given the following parameters, I was able to get a value of 4.478837 via MS Excel's MDURATION Function.

```
# GIVEN:
# settlement_date = "2021-05-15"
# maturity_date = "2025-11-30"
# coupon_rate = 0.00375
# yld_rate = 0.01
# frequency = 2 
# basis = 1
#             
# EXPECTED RESULT: 4.478837
```

I am trying to replicate this using Quantlib Python but I'm getting a different result of 4.32822.
This is my current code

```
import QuantLib as ql
from datetime import datetime 

days_difference = (datetime(2025, 11, 30) - datetime(2021, 5, 15)).days

coupon = 0.00375
yld = 0.01

start = ql.Date(15,5,2021)
maturity = start + ql.Period(days_difference, ql.Days)

bond = ql.FixedRateBond(2, ql.TARGET(), 1000, start, maturity, ql.Period('1Y'), [coupon], ql.ActualActual())
rate = ql.InterestRate(yld, ql.ActualActual(), ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual)
simple_duration = ql.BondFunctions.duration(bond, rate, ql.Duration.Simple)
mod_duration = ql.BondFunctions.duration(bond, rate, ql.Duration.Modified)
mac_duration = ql.BondFunctions.duration(bond, rate, ql.Duration.Macaulay)
print(mac_duration, mod_duration, )

# OUTPUT: (4.349865119875341 4.328223999875962)
```

So how to properly use Quantlib to be able to arrive at 4.478837?

Sorry if this is too basic as I am new to Quantlib and Im still confused on how to use it.

Comment: Just a hint: Your Excel bond has frequency 2, your Quantlib bond seems to have annual payments?

Comment: Also, your yield rate should be `ql.Annual`, no? It is an annual rate of 1%, I understand.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the eval date, and then there are some subleties in how Excel/QL setup discount factors etc.:

```
import QuantLib as ql
```

now, you forgot this step:

```
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(15,5,2021)
```

and then

```
coupon = 0.00375
yld = 0.01
start = ql.Date(15,5,2021)
maturity = ql.Date(30,11,2025)
schedule = ql.Schedule(start, 
                       maturity, 
                       ql.Period('6M'), 
                       ql.NullCalendar(), 
                       ql.Unadjusted, 
                       ql.Unadjusted, 
                       ql.DateGeneration.Backward, 
                       False)

bond = ql.FixedRateBond(0,  1000, schedule, [coupon], ql.ActualActual())
rate = ql.InterestRate(yld, ql.ActualActual(), ql.Compounded, ql.Annual)
mod_duration = ql.BondFunctions.duration(bond, rate, ql.Duration.Modified)
print(100*(mod_duration/4.478837-1))
```

resulting in a % error of:

```
-0.2944451687993066
```

Is that close enough for your applications? If not, you will most likely have to dig deeper into the mechanics of both QL and XL as the differences can result from date rolling, how Excel / ql create the schedule (forward, backwards), *which* Actual/Actual daycounter Excel is implementing etc. Then, there's also the question whether Excel (or ql) uses `1/(1+r)^t` with $t$ a date fraction, `1/(1+r)^(0.5*n)` or any other variant of the discount factor definition, e.g. `exp(-rt)`.

NB: Alternatively, you can set the evaluation date when calling the modified duration:

```
ql.BondFunctions.duration(bond, rate, ql.Duration.Modified,ql.Date(15,5,2021))
```